# Running inspircd on port under 1024

Tags: irc

I have tried running inspircd on port 100
but every time i try i get this error.

WARNING: Not all your client ports could be bound --
starting anyway with 0 of 1 client ports bound.

The following port(s) failed to bind:

1. Address: 0.0.0.0:53     Reason: Permission denied

Hint: Try using a public IP instead of blank or *
InspIRCd is now running as 'irc.server.com'[271] with 1024 max open socket

Comment: That's port 53, not 100. And, don't do this. Just don't.

Comment: I just need help running it on the port.

Answer (score 1):

For binding a port lower than 1024 (part of) the software needs to run with root privileges on linux. And as Michaek Hampton stated: Don't do this.

Also: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l